# Angular acceleration of a charged ring due to changing magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, rotational-dynamics, conservation-laws, torque, electromagnetic-induction

You are given a charged ring and  there exists a changing magnetic field whose rate of change is $A$.

I denote the charge on the ring with $q$, and the mass on ring with $m$.

> *What is the angular acceleration of ring?*

Comment: direction of the field B?

Answer (score 3):

EMF ($\epsilon$) induced in the loop (of radius R) can be obtained from Faraday's law,

\begin{equation}
\epsilon=\oint\vec{E}\cdot\vec{dl}=-\frac{d\phi}{dt}
\end{equation}

Using the above equation, we find that the induced electric field $E$ and hence the torque $\tau$ due to the force $q\vec{E}$ on the loop.

Torque $\tau=I\alpha$ can be used to obtain the angular acceleration $\alpha$ ($I$ is the moment of inertia of the ring).

Comment: This is a very nice answer, but it risks being deleted because it's a complete answer to a "homework-style" problem. I would suggest editing it to only include the method used and not the answer itself.

Comment: @Philip thanks for your concern. I am relatively new to this community, hence didn't know that you are not supposed to write full answers. I'll try to change it.